# Раскрыть select

Tags: javascript, css

Здравствуйте! На сайте есть несколько селектов, которые выводятся с помощью цикла. Каждый селект должен раскрываться по нажатию на определенную кнопку (с помощью js и css). Пока только получается раскрывать все селекты, но никак не отдельно. Т.е. в конечном итоге должно быть так, нажимаем на `Цвет` выпадает список со всеми цветами, а остальные списки не раскрываются. P.S. кол-во селектом в цикле может меняться т.е. не всегда будет равно трем

```js
$('body').on('click', '.bnt', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.dropdown').toggle();
})

$('body').on('click', '.dropdown', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.dropdown').toggle();
})
```

```css
select {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

option {
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="bnt">ЦВЕТ</div>
<div class="dropdown" style="display: none">
  <select size="3" class="color" name="color">
  <option value="grey" class="grey">белый</option>
  <option value="yellow" class="yellow">желтый</option>
  <option value="green" class="green">зеленый</option>
</select>
</div>


<div class="bnt">Форма</div>
<div class="dropdown" style="display: none">
  <select size="3" class="color" name="color">
  <option value="grey" class="grey">Шар</option>
  <option value="yellow" class="yellow">Куб</option>
  <option value="green" class="green">Конус</option>
</select>


</div>



<div class="bnt">Содержимое</div>
<div class="dropdown" style="display: none">
  <select size="3" class="color" name="color">
  <option value="grey" class="grey">Текст1</option>
  <option value="yellow" class="yellow">Текст2</option>
  <option value="green" class="green">Текст3</option>
</select>


</div>
```

Comment: Просто добавляешь .this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', '.bnt', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).next().toggle();
})

 $('body').on('click', '.dropdown', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggle();
})
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uouwd49z/)

Comment: почему-то в `demo` ничего нет, так и должно быть?

Comment: должно быть - поправил :)

Comment: Все круто! Спасибо! А можно сделать так чтобы, если мы нажали на один селект, а потом на другой, то первый селект закрывался, а то сейчас он остается раскрытым? И почему-то верстка внизу страницы плывет (

Comment: например, так  - https://jsfiddle.net/uouwd49z/1/

Comment: то что нужно!) И можно сделать так чтобы селект закрывался если мы нажали куда-то в другое место или в сам селект (например: нажали на 'Цвет', раскрылся список, еще раз нажали на 'Цвет' и список закрылся )?

Comment: очень нужно. Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 5):

Ну вот как-то так. Никакого JS. Если хочешь, чтоб была возможность держать открытыми одновременно несколько селектов, просто вместо `type="radio"` вставляешь `type="checkbox"`

```css
ul{
  cursor:pointer;
}
li, input{
  display:none;
}
input:checked + ul li{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="select">
    <ul>Select №1
      <li>Раз</li>
      <li>Два</li>
      <li>Три</li>
    </ul>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="select">
    <ul>Select №2
      <li>Три</li>
      <li>Два</li>
      <li>Раз</li>
  </ul>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="select">
    <ul>Select №3
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  </label>
```